# could not open connection to the host, on port 5887: connection failed

Tags: linux, networking, rhel

I opened port 5887 and 22 in iptables on my redhat 6 box. When I telnet ip port 22, I get a connection but won't get connection for 5887.

I actually disabled iptables and seLinux just to be sure they are not causing this but still getting connection failed.

Any ideas?

```
 ~]# netstat -anp | grep -w LISTEN
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42012             0.0.0.0:*                        LISTEN      1780/jsvc.exec
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:65443             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1528/nailsd
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37349               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1066/rpc.statd
 tcp        0      0 10.1.1.91:9997              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1780/jsvc.exec
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1780/jsvc.exec
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1042/rpcbind
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55443               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1549/nailswebd
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1314/sshd
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1173/cupsd
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1418/master
 tcp        0      0 10.1.1.91:8443              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1780/jsvc.exec
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8443              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1780/jsvc.exec
```

Comment: Do you have a daemon process running on port 5887?  You might want to add the output of `netstat -anp | grep -w LISTEN` to your question.

Comment: I just did. Also, I have a web console using 8443 and netstat shows it is listening but I still cant telnet even 8443. I am only able to telnet 22. @StephenHarris

Comment: Does `telnet 8443` work from `localhost`?

Comment: Like @StephenHarris alludes to, you have no processes listening on 5887

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing (no daemon or process) listening on port 5887.

```
netstat -anp | grep -w LISTEN | grep 5887
```

This won't display anything based on the output you just provided.

You can test this by using netcat to listen on 5887/tcp:

```
netcat -l 5887
```

Then run:

```
netstat -anp | grep -w LISTEN | grep 5887
```

You should now see the `netcat` process is listening. You will also be able to establish a `telnet` connection to it to prove your firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: you are right. I am working with support team of the application to sort this out. Thanks.